# Where does pip install to on Linux when i use --user

Tags: linux, python, pip

I just installed a Python app using `pip2 install pyriscope --user` and now I need to find the installed files, since it seems like the app is built to use the `python` assuming it's python2, when on my system it's actually python3.

Where do I find the location of `--user`-installed pip packages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of Python 2.7, the location, which `--user` installs the package to is:

```
~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

and executables in:

```
~/.local/bin/
```

Comment: in this case how do we import the package in our program, i assume that by default  when we use ```import some_package_name ```  it imports from  ```/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages``` , then wont there be conflict ?